# Image Upload in java (struts2/struts1/spring mvc)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts2, cloud-hosting

I have one website with jsp, java, struts2.  I wanted to upload a profile image into server . This is possible to upload into the server and link with the profile.  I want to store all the uploaded images in another server . 
For example server A hosts the java web application. server B is a purchased space server and I want to upload the images from web application to server B. And the path and link 'll keep in server A database. Is it possible to do this same or any better idea is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible, as long as you have access to path inside Server B from Server A.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very popular design.
Consider the fact that if one of the two servers (A or B) is down, your site will not work, unless server B is mirrored properly.

Links to images can be anywhere on the web, as long as you provide the full path in the link.
Also, make sure that server B can withstand the load, since every request for a page on server A with a link to an image on server B will obviously require both servers to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , I have found the solution.
Approach #1: 
In java application you can upload your image to your current server(A) and store with c://somefolder/ . Then from the java application transfer the image using httpclient to a different server (B) which is in php/mysql and another domain name.(Php process is easy to store and access). After the transfer process get the result ,file name ,url and store it with your server A database. And in successful transfer delete the file from server A folder. Now u can user the image path as server B domainname/appname/imagepath .

Approach #2:
The same process you can use with amazon web services. (if you don't want to use the second domain name of yours.